# What distasteful result is also produced by this sequence? How can it easily be avoided?

Tags: opcode, machine-code, lc3

The 2's complement of a number can be obtained by complementing the number and adding 1. Therefore, assuming the values A and B are in R0 and R1, what sequence of three instructions perform "A minus B" and writes the result in R2?

This is for an example the book uses overviewing the LC-3 ISA.

First line is just to number the binary for better explanation. NOT (opcode = 1001), ADD (opcode = 0001). Opcode is located [15:12]. Bits [11:9] specify destination register. Bits [8:6] specify source register. Bit [5] specify whether the instruction uses immediate addressing mode (if bit [5] = 1) or register addressing mode (if bit [5] = 0) Bits [5:0] must contain all 1’s when using the NOT (opcode = 1001). So the three following bit codes represent the answer given in the text,

"introduction to computing systems: from bits and gates to c and beyond"

```
15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
 |  |  |  |  |  | | | | | | | | | | |

 1  0  0  1  0  0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 --NOT-----  --R1-- --R1- -----------

 0  0  0  1  0  0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
 --ADD-----  --R2-- --R1- - ----1----

 0  0  0  1  0  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
 --ADD-----  --R2-- --R0- ----- -R2--
```

What distasteful result is also produced by this sequence? How can it easily be avoided?

Sorry if it is not clear. Please feel free to ask me for any other information on this question.

Comment: I believe it's because there is now values in registers R1 and R0 that are no longer being used. But I am not sure at all. It's not an exercise question but it was asked at the end of the example and I am just very curious.

Comment: been a while since I played with lc-3, my guess is you are on the right track, take the two possible solutions (or more) and look at everything affected, how many registers can you get away with, how much memory is used with constants or instructions, and what flags are affected, performance of more instructions, etc...then try to figure out what was meant by "distasteful result".  I cant see how something can be that bad, it is likely someones opinion using words like that, so you have to get into their thinking on this.

Answer (score 1):

R1 is left with a garbage value.

If we did

```
NOT R2, R1
ADD R2, R2, 1
ADD R2, R0, R2
```

Then R1 still has R1, R0 still has R0 and R2 has the result.  So, if there are other operations that use the initial values, we don't have to reload the values from memory.  If we did

```
NOT R1, R1
ADD R1, R1, 1
ADD R2, R0, R1
```

Then R1 has -R1, R0 has R0 and R2 has the result.  If we need to repeatedly decrement numbers by the value (say, subtracting an offset for converting characters to digits, etc.), then we only have to do the negation once.  If we did

```
NOT R1, R1
ADD R1, R1, 1
ADD R0, R0, R1
```

Then we save ourselves a register, and R0 could be used as the running value in the case of something that's continually decremented by R1, effectively using it as an accumulator.

However, storing the bitwise NOT of an input register is unlikely to be helpful, and is also destructive.  Sort of a lose-lose.